# How to validate a form in PrimeFaces before executing _blank in onclick event

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I´m dealing with a problem, I want to know if someone can show me a example how can I validate a page before execute the `action` in a button like `commandbutton` in `PrimeFaces`, if the validation is correct, the new tab will open.

I found some example but didn´t understand.

Comment: According to JSF life cycle when you set `required=true` on the component , it wil automatically get validated when you try to submit a form.

Comment: I need to validate other things

Comment: @SRy: read the question title. OP said there something very important which is missing in the question body.

Comment: @BalusC...Oh yeah. I was misled by that question description as opposed to title.Now I got it